# Custom Categories in CKAN

Tags: ckan, metadata

Is it possible to have custom dataset categories appear in the side bar of the 'datasets' tab in CKAN 2.2?

[HealthData.gov](http://www.healthdata.gov/dataset/search/?solrsort=sort_label%20asc) appears to have these categories, but most examples I see have the default Organizations, Groups, Tags, etc categories. [Glasgow's data portal](http://data.glasgow.gov.uk/dataset) is one such example. Is it possible to configure this, and how might one go about it?

Comment: I believe part of this might have to do with the fact that HealthData.gov "is based on Drupal 7 (for www.healthdata.gov) and CKAN 1.7 (for hub.healthdata.gov). We wrote several custom modules to pass data back and forth between Drupal and CKAN." -- from http://www.healthdata.gov/source-code. Unfortunately, the site mentions having code and mysql db dump published soon but the site is a few years old now. I would suggest asking the nice folks in #ckan on freenode IRC about how to add a custom facet to the sidebar.

Answer (score 3):

The filters on the search page sidebar can be configured implementing the [IFacets](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/extensions/plugin-interfaces.html#ckan.plugins.interfaces.IFacets) interface from your own extension (you'll need to write some code for that).

For instance, [these ones](http://data.satapps.org/dataset) are defined like this:

https://github.com/okfn/ckanext-tsbsatellites/blob/master/ckanext/tsbsatellites/plugin.py#L236:L249